# Is it possible to import a subset of big .rds or .feather files into R?

Tags: r, import, feather

I've found good tips about [fast ways to import files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes), but I'm wondering if it is possible to import only a subset of a given file into a variable.

In my case, I have a file with 16 million rows saved as .rds (and also as .feather, as I was playing with the speed of both formats) and I'd like to import a subset of it (say, a few rows or a few columns) for initial analysis.

Is it possible? The readRDS() does not seem to accept any subsetting, while read_feather() does not seem to allow row selection (although you can specify the columns). Should I consider another data format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'. A nice alternative is the `fst` file format, which does allow the retrieval of a selection of columns and rows from a large dataset. More info [here](http://www.fstpackage.org/).

Comment: A bit late to the party but +1 for fst - I'm using it a lot now and the performance is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Using `readr::read_csv` you could use `n_max` parameter and read as many rows as you like.

With `readRDS`, I suppose you could read the file `dplyr::sample_n` and then just erase it from memory with `rm(object)`.

If you can not read the whole file into memory, you could use either `sqlite`, or another database, which is the prefered way, or you could try something along the line of `readr::read_delim_chunked`, which alows you to read a file in chunks, do something with the read chunk (like sample_n), delete the read chukc from memory and keep just the callback's result and go on like that until the file is over.

Comment: I believe `readr()` cannot import .rds or .feather files, so does not work for my case. With the `readRDS()` option, I'd need to import the whole file first, subset it and remove the big one, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. All in all, it seems that the answer is no, that's not possible to import a subset of a .rds or a .feather file.

Comment: That is one of the reasons you need databases for

Comment: I'll check your `sqlite` suggestion. Thank you.